# Regex xpath expression in Selenium automation

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm having trouble capturing the regex in xpath for list of web elements in Selenium Web driver automation.

I have new, change, old tabs on the page.

`//a[@data-target='#newFieldsTab']`

I tried match but it didn't worked.

Eg:

`//a[matches(@data-target='FieldsTab')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the xPath expression

`//a[contains(@data-target,'FieldsTab’)]`